# Скопировать и вставить содержимое атрибута

Tags: php

Добрый день нужно прописать скопировать содержимое title и вставить в alt и загвоздка в том что я имею только на выходе 1 переменную `$product_stickers`
и с помощью её нужно все это сделать.

Comment: То есть значение title и alt находится в переменной $product_stickers или как?

Comment: @DmitriyKondratiuk в переменной <img src="/delivery-car-180x30.png" title="бесплатной доставкой">
Я бы контроллер поправил и добавил бы alt но проблема в том что контроллер зашифрован

Comment: Я так понимаю вам лучше атрибут менять уже на фронтенде через jquery

Comment: @DmitriyKondratiuk я честно говоря думал об этом. Но насколько это правильно не знаю :) Спасибо попробую

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
 $(document).ready(function(){
   var title_text = $("title").text();
   $("img").attr("alt", title_text);
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Some title</title>
</head>    
<body>
<img src="/delivery-car-180x30.png" title="бесплатной доставкой">
</body>
</html>
```